OfficeJS - Outlook Web Add-in using OpenId Authentication
I've a VSTO Add'In running in Outlook to integrate some emails with a Web Application in .NET Framework 4.8 that uses openid authentication.
Now, Microsoft released the new version of Outlook that no longer supports VSTO Add'In and I might need to upgrade to OfficeJS/Web Add'In. I rely on Keycloak to support OpenId Authentication and I need to call a Web Application to get/post some data, so I need to get an access token.
I found javascript adapter code for keycloak online and tried to implement that in my plugin. I have followed below steps.
var keycloak = new Keycloak({
    url: 'https://localhost:8443/auth',
    realm: 'DevTeamRealm',
    clientId: 'devteam-client'

});

keycloak.init({
    promiseType: 'native', onLoad: 'login-required'
}).then(function (authenticated) {
    console.log(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
}).catch(function () {
    console.log('failed to initialize')
});

I've face severals problems like:

OutlookOnTheWeb page cannot load the Keycloak JS adapter, as the Keycloak login page has “Content Security Policy directive” is set to “frame-ancestors ‘self’”. Therefore, the Keycloak page is not meant to be displayed within an I-Frame.  Even if I remove the restriction on Keycloak - Realm Settings - Security Defenses, I've run into problems with cookies.
Desktop Outlook cannot use the adapter as MS Add-In does not explicitly support “window.history.replace”.

How can I implement openId authentication using Keycloak as Identity Provider in Office Web AddIn to call external web api's?

You should post a link to this "adapter" and perhaps post on the github page for that adapter. I'm wondering how this adapter works, why can't you create your own "login page" that captures the USER/PWD, but I'm only somewhat familiar w/ Keycloak.

@FreeSoftwareServers, I can't create my own login page because the user should not give his credentials on any page than the page of Identity Provider. In this case, the identity provider is Keycloak, so no one knows the password, except the Keycloak itself (in this case client-credentials flow is not a good option because security concerns).
